# How can I get my ellipses formatted correctly in XeTeX?

Tags: spacing, symbols, xetex, punctuation

I've been using `\dots` and `\ldots` to try to get ellipses happening.

Ellipses should look like this: Some text . . . and then some more text.

But instead they look like this: Some text ...and some more text.

I'm using XeTeX with the `mla` style from the texlive-humanities Ubuntu package. I should also add that I'm very new to TeX and have almost no idea what I'm doing. The top of my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}

%Xelatex Stuff
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra} 

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that if you include [the `ellipsis` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ellipsis), and use it as `\ldots\`, it seems to produce the correct results:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}

%Xelatex Stuff
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{ellipsis} 

%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
Elipses should look like this: Some text~\ldots\ and then some more text. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does work for me, but only if I include the ellipiss package _after_ the polyglossia package. So it appears polyglossia is redefining the space somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try the ellipsis character, … ? One of the main benefits of XeTeX is that you can use the correct unicode characters directly.

Comment: Good point. I wrote the whole thing in LaTeX form, and then discovered that I could use XeTeX, but now I have all this LaTeX syntax and I'm kicking myself for spending all this time typing ``quotes like this''.